# How to adjust child view height after resizing its parent ViewGroup?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have custom view which extends `RelativeLayout` and has child element with `height` set to "fill_parent".
The problem is that adjusting parents height doesn't affect its child height.
How can I force child to fit its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programatically change height\width with LayoutParams, check this:
[How to create a RelativeLayout programmatically with two buttons one on top of the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979212/programmatically-creating-a-relativelayout-in-android)