# How to overlay 2 imageviews specifying the position

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to place 2 ImageViews, one above the other. 
Here is an example with a square and a circle.

[image]

How can I do that? I know only in runtime what images to use, so I cannot specify them in an xml file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *tries brushing dirt off screen*  .... oh

Comment: ahahahahahaha sorry XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) to stack views on each other.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/img_green" />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/img_red"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

then you may set `android:layout_margin=""` to properly position the `ImageView`s.

Note that the last child of `FrameLayout` is the top most visible view

Answer (score 0):

You should specify their location inside the layout programmatically, this is not exactly what you are asking for, but you will get an idea of what you have to do :

[How to create a RelativeLayout programmatically with two buttons one on top of the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979212/programmatically-creating-a-relativelayout-in-android)

Since absolute layout is deprecated you probably have to play with margins.