# how to add editText in a multiselection dialog in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, multi-select

i am new to android development. i want a multiselection dialog with edittExt
. i dont want to create ant row.xml. i want to add dynamically edittext in my multiselect dialog. i dont know how to do that.. if some one can help me...
my code for multiselect dialog is....

```
public class MultiSelectionDialogExample extends Activity 
    {
        protected CharSequence[] _options = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" };
        protected boolean[] _selections =  new boolean[ _options.length ];

        protected Button _optionsButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _optionsButton = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button );
    _optionsButton.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler()  );
    }

    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick( View view ) {
            showDialog( 0 );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id ) 
    {
        return 
        new AlertDialog.Builder( this )
            .setTitle( "Planets" )
        .setMultiChoiceItems( _options, _selections, new DialogSelectionClickHandler() )
            .setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogButtonClickHandler() )
            .create();
    }


    public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener
    {
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected )
        {
            Log.i( "ME", _options[ clicked ] + " selected: " + selected );
            }
        }


        public class DialogButtonClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
    {
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked )
                {
                    switch( clicked )
                    {
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        printSelectedPlanets();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void printSelectedPlanets(){
            for( int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++ ){
                Log.i( "ME", _options[ i ] + " selected: " + _selections[i] );
            }
        }
    }
```

how to add edittext in each row in this dialog...please guys tell me proper solution for my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create the view programmatically, mush like on the link below.

[How to create a RelativeLayout programmatically with two buttons one on top of the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979212/programmatically-creating-a-relativelayout-in-android)

but insted of setting the view on the acitivity you will pase the value to the public method "setview" on the dialog.