# Can't add RelativeLayout programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-relativelayout

i have some xml layout file.this is a my xml layout source code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#ff0000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_categorry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i try to add new RelativeLayout programmatically,bellow my 'rot' layout.i wrote some code but i can't add new layout this is a my source

```
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            final RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(
                    getApplicationContext());

            Button add_btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            add_btn.setText("Click to add TextViiews and EditTexts");
            ll.addView(add_btn);

            parms.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.rot);
            ll.setLayoutParams(parms);
        }
    });
```

as i said i can't add layout.what am i doing wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: Do you want to add a relative layout with a button inside?

Comment: So Just now add your `ll` layout to your main parent `Relativelayout`.

Comment: If you're adding more views to the relativelayout, you'd be better off just designing a custom view and instantiating that to add to the parent view, instead of having reams of code adding individual components at runtime.

Comment: @ Blaze Tama i want to add new layout bellow my 'rot' layout.layout witch i have  xml file

Comment: You must first findviewbyid rot, then added your view to it.

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4979362/2574791). this code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create object of your main Relative Layout.

```
       RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainRelativeLayout);
       main.addView(ll);
```

add above code after ll.setLayoutParams(parms);

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding the layout to the root view. Call:

```
((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.rot)).addView(ll);
```

Answer (score 0):

after this line:

```
 ll.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

added this code:

```
RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout).findViewById(R.id.rot);
root.addView(ll);
```