# Fullscreen DialogFragment with translucent StatusBar

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, statusbar, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment which I want to show in fullscreen. I do however still want a StatusBar present, and the hardware buttons at the bottom. I also want to set a background color of the StatusBar (for Lollipop).

My problem is that if I set the following flags in the DialogFragment:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);   
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

Both the StatusBar and Hardware keyboard becomes translucent, and the DialogFragment stretches behind these.

Here is the code, which has been greatly reduced to become readable:

```
public class CardDetailsDialog extends DialogFragment {

Setup parameters...

public static CardDetailsDialog newInstance(final long cardId, final long projectId){
    CardDetailsDialog frag = new CardDetailsDialog();
    frag.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CardDetailsDialogStyle);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(getDialog() != null) {
        getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogSlideAnimation;
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        getDialog().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_details, container, false);

    Handle everything that happens inside the view...

    return view;
}
}
```

Here is the referred theme:

```
<style name="CardDetailsDialogStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" >
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
</style>
```

And the style of the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/pp.whiteBackgroundColor" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_details_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/PopupMenutheme">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/details_scrollview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        All subview elements here...

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result: [image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the ToolBar extends over the StatusBar and hardware buttons. I don't know if I am approaching this correctly. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

This is what the same view look likes when I remove

```
getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who's still having this problem, do the following. This just solves ***half of the problem that is posted i.e. black status bar***.

Add following theme to ***res/value-v21/style***

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
     <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

And then apply Style on `DialogFragment` in `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.DialogTheme);
}
```

***Edit***
if you've problem with your dialog theme then use this style e.g. `colorAccent` or `colorControlHighlight` etc

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
     <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: This saved me! Setting android:windowTranslucentStatus to true does the trick, crazy

Answer (score 7):

In my case `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE` solved problem with overlapping

```
        int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width,height);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            dialog.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkGrayTransp));
            dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);//solves issue with statusbar
            dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL| Gravity.TOP);
        }
```

Comment: This solution worked for me... without the line dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE); Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Try use the same Style from your App. I tested with simple dialog without fragment and works fine.
Like that:

```
new Dialog(context, R.style.CardDetailsDialogStyle);
```

Comment: What is the " CardDetailsDialogStyle" ?

Comment: @ThangBA CardDetailsDialogStyle is style that is applied to activity

Answer (score 2):

You have to set fitsystemwindows = true. Other way is to add a Space with 0dp and change its height to 25dp when the dialog is going to show.

To change the space size, use layout params, check this post: [How to create a RelativeLayout programmatically with two buttons one on top of the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979212/programmatically-creating-a-relativelayout-in-android)

Comment: Maybe can be that the elevation of the dialog is less than the toolbar.

Comment: I am not following, could you please elaborate?

Comment: In appcompat 21 for lollipop, you can set elevation in the xml. If you are using a toolbar, maybe it has more elevation than the dialog.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Here is some documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFitsSystemWindows(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to your root ViewGroup:

```
`<FrameLayout

android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<View .../>
```