# Navigate to previous Activity

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-intent, screen

I have two screens, in second screen i have one back button that shows the first screen(using intent). if i click that back button from second screen i navigated to first screen no probs in that.. now i want to navigate back to second screen automatically without clicking any button. Please help me how can i do this. Thanks for ur valuable time .

Comment: its a little bit unclear that what you want.

Comment: what exactly is going to trigger the "navigate back to second screen" ? Is there some sort of user interaction or a timeout?

Comment: yes i used thread in the second screen,after 2 seconds it should trigger

Comment: Why don't you call the intent in the thread?

Comment: i tried intent, now the problem is state not maintained and it restart the activity.

Answer (score 1):

I would give a try to a `ViewFlipper` activity, with two screens. This, of course, if you can encapsulate your actions into one activity (which i'm sure is manageable with `AsyncTasks` / `Threads`, `Services` and `Handlers`).

This way you can use gestures, (soft/hard)buttons, dropdowns, -whatever-, to navigate between your screens.

Comment: its easy..you have knowledge about how to set Dynamic relative layout's child relativity??

Comment: You have to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` when adding the new view to the `RelativeLayout`. In that instance you can add rules to where to put the new view. You should take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically), it has a nice example as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically go back to a previous activity on the Activity stack by calling the `finish()` method.

If you want to do this without any user interaction, use a `Handler` that automatically calls `finish()` on your activity after a predefined timeout (see  [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) for more information on Handlers).

Answer (score 0):

try with Thread.sleep([ms]) and then call finish or call intent to the first

Answer (score 0):

The one solution is, when you press BACK button from second screen instead of call finish(); you should start first activity again, so the activity stack will be

```
FIRST
SECOND
FIRST
```

so after the delay of two second your activity will finish and eventually will come back to second screen, and state will be maintained also.