# adding a layout to another layout

Tags: android, layout

sir a need to add a layout to another layout on click of a button.

Is it possible how.

Comment: This is not a forum, so you have to specify your problem and show us what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Example here:
[How to lay out Views in RelativeLayout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

It is. Add this code to the onClickListener of your button:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(...);

// init this layout here

RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
parentLayout.addView(layout);
```