# Android: Adding a EditText programatically when a button is pressed

Tags: android, layout

I am working on an SMS application. I have a "+" button so that when user clicks that button a new ExitText will appear under the existing one for user to enter multiple phone numbers to send the text. Can anyone please help with creating a new EditText when a button is pressed?

Thank You,

Comment: show your layout where + button is.also where you want to add EditText.It is all about adding view in the layout

Comment: @rds: I am sorry, but I am new to Android and just started to work with it. I tried to google it but could not find it and thts y i posted a question here.

Answer (score 5):

I would keep a `List` of `EditText` objects and add a new one

```
EditText toAdd = new EditText(this);
list.add(toAdd);
```

to the list on button press. Also, read this link for how to add that new `EditText` to your current layout.  [How to lay out Views in RelativeLayout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically)

When you know the user is done and wants to save the numbers, iterate through your `List` of `EditText` objects.

Comment: Thank you for help, I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

I built an app that adds buttons dynamically based on how many rows there on in my database.

basically I found it easier to create an array of buttons with length equal to the number of buttons I need:
In your case...

```
final int PHONE_NUMBERS = 0;

final int OTHER_STUFF = 1;

final int MORE_STUFF = 2;

LinearLayout MyEditTextLayout;

EditText []DynamicFields = new EditText[3];

*note these should be declared outside of onCreate*

then within onCreate {

MyEditTextLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.Whatever_you_named_your_layout_in_xml);

}

then in your onClickListener dialog:

final EditText editText = new EditText();

if(button = myPhoneNumberButton)
{

editText.layout_width = "fill_parent";

editText.hint = "Enter Phone Numbers Here";

DynamicFields[PHONE_NUMBERS] = editText; //that way you can refer to your editTexts later

MyEditTextLayout.addView(editText);

}
```

*please note I typed this out quickly at work so the code might not work exactly as is but this should give you a good start* Comment if you have any questions!

Answer (score -1):

In order to create a dialog with an EditText inside, you can do this in the button's OnClickListener:

```
final FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(ContactView.this);
final EditText txtSms = new EditText(ContactView.this);
txtSms.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
txtSms.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
txtSms.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
txtSms.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
txtSms.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
fl.addView(txtSms, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactView.this);
        //building the custom AlertDialog
        builder.setView(fl).setTitle("Enviar mensaje").setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    //What happens when the positive button is pressed
            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which){
                if(txtSms.getText().toString().length() != 0){
                    enviarSms(txtSms.getText().toString());
                    d.dismiss();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(((Dialog) d).getContext(), "Can't send an empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
                    //What happens when the negative button is pressed
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {
                d.dismiss();
            }
        }).create().show();
```