# How do you make an android layout hold widgets programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a custom home screen application and can't seem to find an article or a book that explains how to add widgets to a layer programmatically. Anyone know of any good tutorials or a book where I can find this information as a Google search only returned me articles on how to make a widget. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question in Google or something. Anyway, thank you!

EDIT: Since I don't have 100 reputation yet I can't answer my own question... which is... ah nvm...

This is the answer... the only one I could find: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/appwidgethost-tutorial-t10329.html

It works but you have to really take the time to understand it. Anyway it's the only real... example I could find I guess.

Comment: i think  you talking about theme?

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about how to make an android application host widgets. I found this resource and I think it's the answer but I have to go through it first http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/appwidgethost-tutorial-t10329.html

Comment: It almost works that example just that it crashes right before adding the widget to the screen. Still don't know why yet.

Comment: I think U need this link, Please use this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically