# View & layout vs setGravity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a View to a Layout and put the View at the bottom of the screen.
here is my code

```
RelativeLayout game = new RelativeLayout(this);
game.addView(new Menu(this));
game.addView(ad.getAd());
game.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
setContentView(game);
```

But the View gets printed on the top of the screen, why isnt setGravity working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gravity don't works in RelativeLayout.

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(null);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, -1);
Menu menu = new Menu();
menu.setLayoutParams(params);
ad.getAd().setLayoutParams(params);
game.addView(menu);
game.addView(ad.getAd());
```