# Add TextView on top of Button?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a contacts app which displays big contact photos. I need to add a label with the contacts name of each contact on top of the button (near the bottom) however I don't know how to get two views on top of each other. I cannot simply use settext since I need to add a semi-transparent background to the label.

---

EDIT:
I managed to get it on top but I cannot figure out how to get it on the bottom of the button.

```
RelativeLayout icon = new RelativeLayout(context);
// Create button
Button button = new Button(context);
button.setLayoutParams(new    LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
layout.addView(button);
// Create label
TextView label = new TextView(context);
label.setText(name);
label.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(120, 0, 0, 0));
label.setLayoutParams(new      LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
icon.addView(button);
icon.addView(label);
```

However the text appears on the top of the image and I want it to be on the bottom like this:

[image]

With xml this would be something like: `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myButton"` but I'm doing this programatically and I haven't found a way to do it. How can I place my label near the button?

Comment: Try using FrameLayout and inside that layout u can add button and label which will be one above other.

Comment: check my updated question, I managed to get most of the work done. If you can just tell me how to move it to the button I'll accept the answer!

Comment: If possible provide some sample screen how you want the UI should look.

Comment: I just added a mockup. Please check it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do this you can use a frame layout. The documentation for frame layout can be found here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

However, frame layout is depreciated (if I remember correctly). So instead I would recommend using a relative layout. In your relative layout you can set the position of the button and then give the textview the attributes `android:layout_alignLeft=@id/something`and `android:layout_alignRight="@id/Something"`

Comment: I know how to do that on xml, I just do `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"` however I'm creating both things dynamically

Comment: I hope Framelayout is not deprecated

Comment: @Liso22 I have not created a layout using layout params before, but if you can set the layout_gravity of the view, then use the frame layout and give your text view a gravity within the layout

Comment: @Prasad - maybe it is not fully depreciated, but I believe that developers were encouraged at some point to use relative layouts instead

Comment: How do I change the alignBottom programatically?

Comment: @Liso22 Look here, at the addRule method. It should help(but you will need to play around with the attributes a little bit) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically

Comment: `lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, button.getId());` did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="John"
            android:background="@drawable/button_action_active" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="test textView" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Sample screen shot for above code]

**Dynamically you can do by**

```
 TextView lable = new TextView(this);  
        lable.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
        lable.setTextSize(25);  
        lable.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);  
        lable.setText("John");  


        Button button = new Button(this);  
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_action_active);  
        button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  

        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);  
        fl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
        fl.addView(button);  
        fl.addView(lable);  

        setContentView(fl);
```

Comment: I just tried it, anyway I know how to do it in XML. However I'm creating both things dynamically and don't know how to set the TextView to the bottom of the container. (What would be `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myButton"` in xml)

Comment: I need to put the label at the bottom of the layout. That's my only problem right now.