# How to turn static AdMob code into dynamic code

Tags: android

I'm adding *AdMob* to my application. Apparently I need to add the following layout snippet to each one of my layouts:

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

However, I'd rather add the above snippet dynamically, instead of copy-pasting it into each layout.

What I am having trouble with is translating the following snippet:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
```

into Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options (at least):

1. Remove on the XML the `android:layout_below="@+id/button2"`and add this property on code, like says on this question:
   [How to lay out Views in RelativeLayout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically)
2. The other option is create an xml layout with only the code that you post on your question, without the `android:layout_below="@+id/button2"`. Then in each layout that you want to use this, use the include element: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Hope it helps.