# Changing image/button location (relatively) in Android

Tags: android, image, button, layout

I have a toggleButton I want to change its location (in runtime, not in layout XML) according to user preference. 
I looked and all I found was AbsoluteLayout which is not what I want (I need relative to screen edges). 
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` and set your `toggleButton` relatively to other `View`s in the `Layout`.

Take a look at this post on how it's done:

[How to lay out Views in RelativeLayout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically)

**Example:**

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setText("B");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv2.getId());

layout.addView(tv2, lp);
```

To edit the margins for the view use the LayoutParams object like so:

```
 lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Comment: Thanks, I read that , but i still have some parts missing : 1. The layout will save rules i don't overwrite ? 2. How can i set an object with 'marginTop' for example ? i didn't find this command in the 'RelativeLayout.'

Comment: to add Margin top you need to spicify the margins in the layoutParam parameter like this: lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

Comment: what do you mean by rules you don't overwrite?

Comment: I still can't understand how i can set my image to be I.E. 50 px from top 40 px from left ?

Comment: first of all don't ever work with pixels... it will cause you problems in different sized screens. to your question you can add you view to be right of parent, and under parent and then set the margins for left and top to 40 and 50 respectively.

Comment: I did the following after initializing the lp (my object is m_lock), `lp.setMargins(50, 40, 0, 0);` and `lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, m_lock.getId());` after that i added the view... no change for the object.