# Android programmatic relative layout: BELOW rule not working?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to create a layout (see class RosterPlayerView below) that comprises an image with text below it and then instantiate that view multiple times in a relative layout. I used relative layout instead of linear as the layout will become more complex.

When I first ran the code below (but without the setId calls) the text appeared **above** the image. Thanks to [this stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically) I discovered that relative layout needs unique widget ids to work. But when I added the setId() calls the text view is not displayed at all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class RosterPlayerView extends RelativeLayout {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    static int layoutId = 100;

    public RosterPlayerView(Context context, int playerId, Drawable photo) {
        super(context);
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        textView = new TextView(context);
        addView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        imageView.setId(layoutId++);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams timeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        timeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView.getId());
        addView(textView, timeLayoutParams);        
        imageView.setImageDrawable(photo);
        textView.setId(layoutId++);
        textView.setText("0:00");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Id of you `imageView` before adding it to the layout.

You can also create a `LinearLayout` with the `imageView` and `textView` inside before adding it to the `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Jeppe, thanks for the help. Sadly textView still not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

a LinearLayout would be an awful lot simpler for what you are trying to do. So would inflating an XML layout, for that matter.

Comment: Philip - you're right linear layout is much simpler. I went with relative layout as I'd like to influence position of textView and add more widgets to layout. Thanks for your help.