# Adapter dynamically created textview is not aligning properly

Tags: android, dynamic, uiview, textview

In my android application i am creating textview dynamically and each textview have onclick with respect to the type which have been send from webservice.

[image]

last text must be aligned to next line, below i have added my layout details

My adapter class

```
ArrayList<GroupTitleVo> titlelist = activitylist.get(position)
                .getTitlelist();
        LinearLayout sample_layout = new LinearLayout(_context);
        sample_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, 0));
        sample_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        for (int i = 0; i < titlelist.size(); i++) {

            if (titlelist.get(i).getType().equals("user")) {
                TextView user_text = new TextView(_context);
                user_text.setId(i);
                user_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                user_text.setTextSize(12);
                user_text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                user_text.setText(" "+titlelist.get(i).getName());
                user_text.setTag(titlelist.get(i).getId()+"~"+titlelist.get(i).getName());

                user_text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String id = (String) v.getTag();
                        Toast.makeText(_context, "user id" + id,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String[] name = id.split("~");
                        listener.userProfileredirect(name[0],name[1]);
                    }
                });

                holder.horizontaltext.addView(user_text);
            } else if (titlelist.get(i).getType().equals("verb")) {
                TextView verb_text = new TextView(_context);
                verb_text.setId(i);
                verb_text.setText(" "+titlelist.get(i).getName());
                verb_text.setTextSize(10);
                verb_text.setTag(titlelist.get(i).getId());
                holder.horizontaltext.addView(verb_text);
            } else {
                TextView group_text = new TextView(_context);
                group_text.setId(i);
                group_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                group_text.setTextSize(14);
                group_text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                group_text.setTag(titlelist.get(i).getId() + "~"
                        + titlelist.get(i).getType());
                group_text.setTextSize(12);
                group_text.setText(" "+titlelist.get(i).getName());

                group_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String id = (String) v.getTag();
                        Toast.makeText(_context, "Group ID" + id,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String idtype[] = id.split("~");
                        if (idtype.length > 1) {
                            listener.userGroupRedirect(idtype[1], idtype[0]);
                        }
                    }
                });

                holder.horizontaltext.addView(group_text);
            }

        }
```

And XML parent layout

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/textlinearlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/posted_person_img_view_id"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
```

Kindly help me to align this textviews

Comment: Adding a `View` to a horizontal `LinearLayout` is just going to stick that `View` on the end. You could either use a nested vertical `LinearLayout` in your current setup to which to add the `View`, or use a `RelativeLayout` for the item's root `View`, and set `RelativeLayout.END_OF` and `RelativeLayout.BELOW` rules on the new `View`'s `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make nested layouts.

**LinearLayout**

You have to set horizontally `LinearLayout`, so you have all items in one horizontal line. You need to put into your existing `LinearLayout` your `ImageView` and create into it another `LinearLayout` set vertically to have two `TextView` items one below another.

Your view should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_gallery"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="First text"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Second text text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In existing code create another `LinearLayout`, set orientation of it as vertical and copy into it your two `TextView`s.

**RelativeLayout**

You need to declare a position of every item, just like in this example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_gallery"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="First text"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Second text text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I used here XML files, because I think it might be more clear to see what attributes and views you would need to use.

EDIT: To create `RelativeLayout` programmaticaly read:

[How to lay out Views in RelativeLayout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically)

Hope it help.

Comment: i want to create dynamically may be textview will increase up to 20, in that case how can i use xml

Comment: Madhu, look at your code. You have already `LinearLayout` with three elements. I think the easiest way to you would be change Linear into Relative and add to your views position arguments like `textView1.toTheRightOf(textView2)`. I never used layouts as  you, I always define a .xml layout files and then write a code

Comment: Thanks for the link, it gives idea to create textview dynamically, as like mike suggest

Comment: @Madhu if you still would have a question, the issue is still open and you haven't accepted my answer  as solution :-)

Comment: i dont think that your answer is correct, only your link helped me to get some idea in that case how can i accept your answer